# Why my Admob is not working?

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob

I just published a game I made using Unity3D to Google Play. When I made tests before putting the game on the strore - I was able to see test ads. Now, that my game is on the store - I can't see any banner ads.

This is my code for showing adds, what's wrong here?

```
BannerView BV;    
string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-123456789/987654321";    

void Start()
{
    BV = new BannerView(adUnitId, AdSize.Banner, AdPosition.Top);
    RB(); //Request Banner
    SB(); //Show Banner
}

private AdRequest createAdRequest()
{
    return new AdRequest.Builder()           
          .AddKeyword("Game")
          .SetGender(Gender.Male)
          .SetBirthday(new DateTime(1988, 9, 4))
          .TagForChildDirectedTreatment(true)            
          .Build();
}

void RB()
{
    BV.LoadAd(createAdRequest());       
}

internal void SB()
{
    BV.Show();
}
```

Comment: Perhaps Admob is down? A quick check won't tell you whether it isn't working for certain. Try again a couple times per day, be sure the device is connected to the Internet, no adblocking done on the device or network, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your log. It will tell you if an ad request has been made and what the result was.

If there are no ads to display, it will test you. 
I suspect that is what is happening.